# How can I count the number of Contents in a CustomView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am using down CustomView in my project, which has some jobs to do, I would like to know how can I count the contents of this custom view?

***For example I got 3 Text views in my ContentView, which I like to know how can I calculate the count of it and store it in my CustomView as countOfInPutView.***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        CustomView {
            Text("Hello, world! 1")
            Text("Hello, world! 2")
            Text("Hello, world! 3")
        }
    }
}



struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    
    var inPutView: () -> Content
    
    var countOfInPutView: Int = Int() // : here ???
    
    init(@ViewBuilder inputView: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.inPutView = inputView
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        
        VStack {
            
            inPutView()
            
        }.font(Font.body.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.red)
        
    }
    
}
```

**updated: another approach**

```
inPutView().onAppear() { countOfInPutView += 1; print(countOfInPutView) }
```

Comment: One idea would be to add an `onAppear` to every view inside your `CustomView`. And then you sync them somewhere and count how many you receive. You could of course also do that inside the `init` method. You would have to create another custom wrapper for each view. (recommended)

Comment: @Mofawaw, Not bad Idea at all, I could get it work in onAppear, how you do it in init() ?

Comment: Perfect, I am happy to hear. I think they should work the same?

Comment: @Mofawaw, you said: “You could of course also do that inside the init method. You would have to create another custom wrapper for each view. “ please give me a example code for that, I could not figured out it. mayBe as answer, it would be ok for me as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible approach. The idea is to basically add an `onAppear` to every view inside your `CustomView`. And then you only have to sync them and count how many times you receive an "appear publisher".

Here would be a solution:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomView {
            CustomChildView { Text("Hello, world! 1") }
            CustomChildView { Text("Hello, world! 2") }
            CustomChildView { Text("Hello, world! 3") }
        }
    }
}


enum CustomViewManager {
    
    static let childViewInit = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}


struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let inPutView: () -> Content
    @State private var countOfInPutView: Int = 0
    
    
    init(@ViewBuilder inputView: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.inPutView = inputView
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            inPutView()
        }
        .font(Font.body.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.red)
        .onReceive(CustomViewManager.childViewInit) {
            countOfInPutView += 1
            print(countOfInPutView)
        }
    }
}


struct CustomChildView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let childView: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        childView()
            .onAppear { CustomViewManager.childViewInit.send() }
    }
}
```

[image]

Note:

I have added a wrapper `CustomChildView` for each view inside your `CustomView`, together with a `CustomViewManager`, for managing the "appear publisher" `childViewInit`.

About the `init`-method... you are right, it's not getting triggered. I don't know why. But with `onAppear` it's working fine!